# BCP import issue

Tags: bcp

i am using BCP command to import text file in SQL database.

below is syntax,

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "Database.dbo.TableName" in "\\devm11\RND\2.txt" -c -t"þ|þ" -r -S "SQLservername" -T'
```

As not able to attach text file format, so please find below image for input file..

### Problem:

- This file gives EOF error while importing.
- It's not work with provided field terminators..
- i tried with different terminators like "|" and  "^|" and "|^" but
  nothing works..

Please suggest how to resolve this issue ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What is the row terminator for this file? Is it `\r\n` or `\n`? Also I'm seeing that you have `-r` as a parameter which should specify the row terminator but you have it as blank. If the file has row terminator `\n` you can omit that parameter as it's the default.

Comment: row terminator is \r\n, i also try by giving \r\n in row terminator but it's not working with this input file.

Comment: In that case you need to specify `-r \r`. Source: [Specify Field and Row Terminators (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server)

Comment: tried with -r \r but it's giving error for EOF, i tried to resolve this EOF error but not able to resolve it...but when i updated file with simple deliminator "," then it's working fine, so seems like there is issue with deliminators ""þ|þ"

Comment: AFAICT there's no need to place double quotes around the terminator. So try `-r \r -t þ|þ`.